# How can I find a minimum and maximum from a dice roll?

Tags: c++, random, max, min, dice

I want to find the minimum number, or maximum number, that I could possibly receive if put an X amount of dice and a X amount of dice sides. I know that if I only roll one dice then the minimum would be the "minrange" and the maximum would be the "minrange" + "numOfSides", but if I were to roll multiple dice with X amount of sides; how would I find the minimum/maximum number that could be generated?

```
double rollDice(int numOfDice, int numOfSides, int divide, int minrange) {
    int i = 0;
    subtotal = 0;
    while (i < numOfDice) {
        roll = 0;
        roll = minrange + (rand() % numOfSides);
        subtotal += roll;
        i++;
    }
    return subtotal / divide;
}
```

Comment: Simply - if You have `X` dices, each of which rolls `MIN` at minimum and `MAX` in maximum, then the total minimum is `X * MIN` and the total maximum is `X * MAX`. If You have classic 6-sided dice, it has `MIN = 1`, `MAX = 6`. You roll 3 such dices, then the total minimum is `3 * 1 = 3` and the total achievable maximum is `3 * 6 = 18`. Or have I misunderstood the question?

Comment: @RomanHocke That makes sense, but if I did tell the program to roll 3 dices of which were 6 sides; then all I have to do is multiply the number of sides by the number of dice to achieve max value, but how would it know what the minimum value would be, or would that always be the minrange?

Comment: You must know, what is the minimum number on each dice. If every dice has minimum of `MIN`, then You can roll `X * MIN` at minimum. So if You use classic dices, whose minimal rollable number is `1`, then the minimum that You roll with `X` dices must be `X * MIN = X * 1 = X`. Just imagine three dices in Your hand. The first rolls 1 at minimum, the second one rolls 1 at minimum, too, and the third one rolls 1 at minimum, too. Which adds to minimal roll of three.

Comment: @RomanHocke So MAX = numOfRolls * numOfSides and MIN = minNum(usually 1) * numOfRolls. I think I got the idea, thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Exactly! :-) Always be aware of that You are just modelling the reality. So, just imagine the real situation and the solution will come in Your mind. You're welcome! Have fun with the dices! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>

void rollDice(int numOfDice, int numOfSides, int* minRange, int* maxRange) {
    *minRange = numOfDice;
    *maxRange = numOfDice * numOfSides;
    return;
}

int main() {

    int minRange;
    int maxRange;
    int noDice = 3;
    int noSides = 6;

    rollDice(noDice, noSides, &minRange, &maxRange);

    std::cout << "Minimum range for " << noDice << " dice with " << noSides << "sides is: " << minRange << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Maximum range for " << noDice << " dice with " << noSides << "sides is: " << maxRange << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Firstly, slight mistake in your question, the maximum score for one dice would not be minRange + numOfSides, it would be numOfSides, and for an arbitrary number of dice the minimum score would be noDice * 1 = noDice and the maximum score would be noDice * noSides.

Seen as you want to calculate the minimum and maximum totals of an arbitrary number of arbitrary sided dice, the best way to retrieve two values from a function, without creating a data structure or an array or an object is to use pointers. By passing the address of the variables to store the minRange and maxRange using the & operator the rollDice function can directly access the chunk of memory used to hold those variables and set them to the appropriate values.

This is my first attempt at answering a question, hope it is what you are looking for.

Comment: Yea that's sort of what I was looking for, however I implemented it a little differently. Thanks for showing some different ways though, I only just started C++ a few weeks ago so I'm just grasping the basics. :)